# Record cpu% reading in period

Tags: shell-script

My question is let the user determine the period of recording down the CPU%
reading and my code is like this

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n $1 ps -eo pcpu
```

it's correct or not?$1 is an argument.

Answer (score 0):

$1 stands for the first argument to your script.

So your script would make calls to "ps -eo pcpu" periodically every N seconds, where N is the value passed as the first argument to your script.

As of recording the CPU readings - I wouldn't go for "watch" as it is more for displaying things. See the example below instead - it checks CPU utilization for a user every N seconds (N is passed as the first argument):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
  do
    top -b -n 1 -u "$user" | awk -v user="$user" 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print user, sum; }'
  sleep $1
done
```

Your user can then pipe the output from the script above to a file, E.g. as follows:

```
./cpu_utilization.sh 1 > my_cpu_stats.log
```